# ASP.NET - CSS to Center Label Under ImageButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, label, imagebutton

I'm trying to get a `<asp:Label>` to appear **centered** under a `<asp:ImageButton>`. Right now, the buttons are tied to objects in a `List` and so I have them all in a ListView control like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv_WantedBooks" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="bookImageButton" runat="server" CssClass="BookImageButton" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image.ImageUrl") %>' OnClick="bookImageButton_Click" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Title") %>' CommandName='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="bookVoteCount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Votes") %>' cssclass="VoteFont"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

For this, I have the following CSS:

```
.BookImageButton
{
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    background: #625863;
    height: 220px;
    width: 182px;
}

.VoteFont
{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #C3980D;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Right now, the `<asp:Label>` is appearing to the far right under the ImageButtons. I've been trying various CSS styles to get them centered under, but I've just not been able to get the CSS right.

Does anyone know how I can get the styling just right? Thanks A TON in advance! Also, this *could* be an issue with my Markup design/layout. I'm not opposed to changing that if necessary - I just figured the issue could be fixed via CSS.

[image: example]

Here is an example of what I mean and also the outputted HTML code that is created:

```
<p>
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$lv_WantedBooks$ctrl0$bookImageButton" id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookImageButton_0" title="Pride and Prejudice" class="BookImageButton" src="[blah, blah, this is correct in the output, trust me.]" />
<span id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookVoteCount_0" class="voteFont">1</span>


<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$lv_WantedBooks$ctrl1$bookImageButton" id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookImageButton_1" title="Sense and Sensibility" class="BookImageButton" src="[blah, blah, this is correct in the output, trust me.]" />
<span id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookVoteCount_1" class="voteFont">1</span>

<br />
<div align="center"><h2><b>Don't See Your Choice? Enter it Below!</b></h2>
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tb_NewBookTitle" type="text" id="MainContent_tb_NewBookTitle" style="height:20px;width:275px;" />
<br /></div>
</p>
```

Comment: This is why I don't like Webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the .VoteFont

```
 display: block;
```

[edit] based on your output...

Essentially I am wrapping imagebutton, span in their own divs.  And wrapping both the divs in another div with the css class column.  And span's parent div is styled to align the text to center.

**CSS**

```
.column {
   float:left; position:relative;margin:5px; 
}
```

**Asp.net code**

```
 <div class="column">
        <div>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="bookImageButton" runat="server" CssClass="BookImageButton" ImageUrl="..." /></div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Label ID="bookVoteCount" runat="server" CssClass="VoteFont" Text="1" /></div>
    </div>
```

**Resulting Html**

```
   <div class="column">
   <div>
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$lv_WantedBooks$ctrl0$bookImageButton" id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookImageButton_0" align="bottom" title="Pride and Prejudice" class="BookImageButton" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<span id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookVoteCount_0" class="voteFont">1</span></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div>
<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$lv_WantedBooks$ctrl1$bookImageButton" id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookImageButton_1" title="Sense and Sensibility" class="BookImageButton"  />
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<span id="MainContent_lv_WantedBooks_bookVoteCount_1" class="voteFont">1</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This put the text underneath and to the far left and then caused the ImageButtons to be in one column along the left of the screen rather than in a row.

Comment: do you want them to be next to each other?

Comment: Yes, I want the ImageButtons to be right next to each other rather than in one long 'column'.

Comment: if you want the label under the image and centered you can use above style and also marrgin-left: 90px; If you want them next to each other user ImageAlign property on the control to absmiddle.

Comment: "use ImageAlign property on the control to absmiddle." -- I'm not really sure what you mean there...

Comment: HEY! That works great! Thanks a ton for the detail with the code sample above too!

Answer (score 1):

Give `.VoteFont` a width and apply a margin to it. Margin auto will center it on the container.

```
.VoteFont {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #C3980D;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 80px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This left it looking exactly how it looked already - didn't change the layout at all.

Comment: @JToland: Instead of showing us the webforms code, you should show us the output HTML, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text-align: center;
```

to .VoteFont block

Comment: Nope, I'd tried this (I probably should have mentioned what I'd already tried). This doesn't change a thing from how it looks above.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
.VoteFont
{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #C3980D;
    font-weight: bolder;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**this should do the trick**

```
.VoteFont
{
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #C3980D;
    font-weight: bolder;
    position: relative;
        left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Anything with 'display: block;' makes my ImageButtons go into a 'column' along the far left of the screen (rather than into a nice row)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.BookImageButton
{
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    background: #625863;
    height: 220px;
    width: 182px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.VoteFont
{

    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #C3980D;
    font-weight: bolder;
    position: relative;
    left: -157px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

If This wouldn't work try to replace

```
display: inline-block;
```

with

```
display: inline-table;
```